# jQuery - how do I show the full navbar at certain width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AAmC.png)  
[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcAC0.png)

When I click on the 3 bars button the navbar slides down then when I move my mouse away it slides back up. This is working perfectly fine but when ever I make the browser's width bigger the navbar is not there because in jquery i told it to slide up. How can i set jquery to slide up and down at a certain width and a bigger width just to show my navbar. I would like my navbar to collapse at a small width but at a bigger width i would like the whole navbar to show.

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 200px) {
  #wrapper { width: 300px; }

  #top-content{
    height: 40px;
  }

  #navbar li {
    display: none;
    padding-top: 4%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #navbar ul{
    height: 130px;

  }

  #icon{
    width: 12%;
    float: right;
    border-left: solid 1px;
  }

  #navbar{
    display: none;
  }



}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  #wrapper { width: 450px;}

  #navbar li a {
    display: inline-block;

  }

  #icon{
    display: none;
  }

  #navbar ul{
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 96%;
  }

  #top-content{
    display: none;
  }

  #navbar, #navbar li {
    display: block;
  }

  #navbar li{
    padding-top: 13%;
  }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  #wrapper {width: 680px; }

  #navbar, #navbar li {
    display: block;
  }

  #navbar li{
    padding-top: 13%;
  }

}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  #wrapper { width: 850px; }

  #navbar, #navbar li {
    display: block;
  }

  #navbar li{
    padding-top: 13%;
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<body>

 <div id="wrapper">

  <div id="top-content">
    <img id="icon" src="images/dropdown.png" />
  </div>
      <div id="navbar">

        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#"> Home </li> </a>
          <li> <a href="#"> About Me </li> </a>
          <li> <a href="#"> Contact Me </li> </a>
          <li> <a href="#"> Blog </li> </a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#icon').click(function(){
  $('#navbar, #navbar li').slideDown();
});

$('#navbar,#navbar ul').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#navbar li, #navbar').slideUp(700);

});
```

Comment: Bind an event handler to `$(window).resize()`, and then change the CSS how you need if the window is a certain size.

Comment: Question is extremely unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this snippet in separate window and resize the window to see the difference. I temporarily changed your `img` to a `div` to simulate the menu icon.

```js
var Menu = {
  options: {
    minWidth: 500,
    downDelayMs: 700,
    upDelayMs: 700,
  },
  Init: function() {
    $("#icon").on("click", Menu.SlideDown);
    $(window).on("resize", Menu.AdjustSize);
    Menu.AdjustSize();
  },
  SlideDown: function() {
    $('#navbar, #navbar li').slideDown(Menu.options.downDelayMs);
  },
  SlideUp: function() {
    $('#navbar li, #navbar').slideUp(Menu.options.upDelayMs);
  },
  AdjustSize: function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= Menu.options.minWidth) {
      if (!Menu.windowWidth || Menu.windowWidth < Menu.options.minWidth) {
        $('#navbar,#navbar ul').off("mouseleave", Menu.SlideUp);
        $('#navbar li, #navbar').show();
        $("#top-content").hide();
      }
    } else {
      if (!Menu.windowWidth || Menu.windowWidth >= Menu.options.minWidth) {
        $('#navbar li, #navbar').hide();
        $("#top-content").show();
        $('#navbar,#navbar ul').on("mouseleave", Menu.SlideUp);
      }
    }
    Menu.windowWidth = $(window).width();
  }
};
Menu.Init();
```

```css
.fakeicon {
  background-color: Green;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url("images/dropdown.png");
  cursor: pointer;
}
.fakeicon:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 3px #ccc;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 20px;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 3px #ccc;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 200px) {
  #wrapper {
    width: 300px;
  }
  #top-content {
    height: 40px;
  }
  #navbar li {
    display: none;
    padding-top: 4%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #navbar ul {
    height: 130px;
  }
  #icon {
    width: 12%;
    float: right;
    border-left: solid 1px;
  }
  #navbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  #wrapper {
    width: 450px;
  }
  #navbar li a {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #icon {
    display: none;
  }
  #navbar ul {
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 96%;
  }
  #top-content {
    display: none;
  }
  #navbar,
  #navbar li {
    display: block;
  }
  #navbar li {
    padding-top: 13%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  #wrapper {
    width: 680px;
  }
  #navbar,
  #navbar li {
    display: block;
  }
  #navbar li {
    padding-top: 13%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  #wrapper {
    width: 850px;
  }
  #navbar,
  #navbar li {
    display: block;
  }
  #navbar li {
    padding-top: 13%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="top-content">
    <div id="icon" title="Show Menu" class="fakeicon"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```